# Delete prefix and postfix for a http url using UNIX

Tags: arch-linux

I have a string formatted like the following (but the actual content changes each time):

> Create tabs for abterms in FIPS integrity verification test failed. FIPS integrity verification test failed.FIPS integrity verification test failed.http://file.lab.pek.com/flex/group/Uomcol/result/UOMCOL.7.2p41.11176/2015.Jul.19/152508022/purse.output-20150719-054908.txt.gz

I need to extract the URL from the text; in this case:

> http://file.lab.pek.com/flex/group/Uomcol/result/UOMCOL.7.2p41.11176/2015.Jul.19/152508022/purse.output-20150719-054908.txt.gz

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your output is in a file `foo.txt`, at the command line, run

```
grep '^http' foo.txt | sed 's/\.gz$//' > bar.txt
```

This will save into `bar.txt` only the lines that start (`^`) with `http` (using `grep`), and will remove a trailing `.gz` (using `sed`).

Comment: i need to remove the post fix to gz as well

Comment: You didn't mention that in the sample output! :). Would you please update the question so it's more clear what you're trying to remove?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Answer extracted from edit)</sub>

This works:

```
var= string ; var=${var#*://} ; echo ${var%% *}
```

Comment: This is my code i had put in comments since i cracked it

Comment: @iamnewbie That's what "answer extracted from edit" means. You can post it yourself if you prefer, and accept your own answer, and I'll delete this version